# Помогите исправить код. Нужно что-бы при вызове конструктора First в те массивы что там, добавлялись входные данные и там и сохранялись

Tags: java, массивы, классы, конструктор, frame

Проблема с кодом. Нужно что-бы при вызове конструктора First в те массивы что там, добавлялись входные данные и там и сохранялись. До сегодняшнего времени я думала что он так и работает, но при вызове методов: serchCity, serchSex или serchAbonent он должен был сравнивать данные и при вызове в ActionListener в JOptionPane.showMessageDialog должен выводить данные которые подошли по сравнению, а он почему-то этого не делает. Код:

```
package mainkursova;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
class First {
    static String[] mist, telefone, poll, all;
    static int i = 0;
    First(){
        
    }
    First(String p, String im, String b, String m, String a, String t, String pol){
        mist = new String[100];
        telefone = new String[100];
        poll = new String[100];
        all = new String[100];
        i++;
        mist[i] = m;
        telefone[i] = t;
        poll[i] = pol;
        all[i] = (p+" "+im+" "+b+" "+m+" "+a+" "+t+" "+pol);
        
    }
    public String[] serchCity(String n){
        int h;
        h = 0;
        String[] endRezult = new String[100];
        for(int b = 0; b< mist.length; b++){
            if (n==mist[b]){
                endRezult[h] = all[b];
            }
        }
        return endRezult;
    }
    public String[] serchSex(String n){
        int h;
        h = 0;
        String[] endRezult = new String[100];
        for(int b = 0; b< poll.length; b++){
            if (n==poll[b]){
                endRezult[h] = poll[b];
            }
        }
        return endRezult;
    }
    public String[] serchAbonent(String n){
        int h;
        h = 0;
        String[] endRezult = new String[100];
       
        for(int b = 0; b< telefone.length; b++){
            
            if (n == telefone[b]){
                endRezult[h] = all[b];
            }
        }
        return endRezult;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Мій Телефонний Довідник");
        frame2.setTitle("Список Абонентів");
        frame.setSize(500, 400);
        frame.setLocation(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame2.setSize(500, 400);
        frame2.setLocation(500, 500);
        frame2.setVisible(false);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        
        frame.add(panel);
        
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(mb);
        JMenu serch = new JMenu("Пошук за..");
        JMenuItem serchSex = new JMenuItem("статтю");
        JMenuItem serchCity = new JMenuItem("містом");
        JMenuItem serchCode = new JMenuItem("кодом оператора");
        serch.add(serchSex);
        serch.add(serchCity);
        serch.add(serchCode);
        mb.add(serch);
        JMenu serch2 = new JMenu("Робота з записами");
        JMenuItem show = new JMenuItem("показати");
        JMenuItem edit = new JMenuItem("дозволити редагувати");
        JMenuItem delete = new JMenuItem("видалити всю інформацію");
        serch2.add(show);
        serch2.add(edit);
        serch2.add(delete);
        mb.add(serch2);
        
        
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("прізвище");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("ім’я");
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("по батькові");
        JLabel label4 = new JLabel("місто");
        JLabel label5 = new JLabel("домашня адреса");
        JLabel label6 = new JLabel("стать (м/ж)");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("телефон");
        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(label2);
        panel.add(label3);
        panel.add(label4);
        panel.add(label5);
        panel.add(label6);
        panel.add(label);
        
        
        JTextField prizvyshe = new JTextField(8);
        JTextField imya = new JTextField(8);
        JTextField pobatkovi = new JTextField(8);
        JTextField misto = new JTextField(8);
        JTextField adresa = new JTextField(8);
        JTextField telefon = new JTextField(8);
        JTextField POL = new JTextField(8);
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
        text.setEnabled(false);
        
        panel.add(prizvyshe);
        panel.add(imya);
        panel.add(pobatkovi);
        panel.add(misto);
        panel.add(adresa);
        frame2.add(text);
        panel.add(POL);
        panel.add(telefon);
        
        
        JButton mainprofesor = new JButton("добавити в довідник");
        panel.add(mainprofesor);
        mainprofesor.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                
                String h = text.getText();
                text.setText(h+'\n'+prizvyshe.getText()+" "+imya.getText()+" "+pobatkovi.getText()+" "+misto.getText()+" "+adresa.getText()+" "+POL.getText()+" "+telefon.getText()+'\n');
                new First(prizvyshe.getText(),imya.getText(),pobatkovi.getText(),misto.getText(),adresa.getText(),telefon.getText(),POL.getText());
                prizvyshe.setText("");
                imya.setText("");
                pobatkovi.setText("");
                misto.setText("");
                adresa.setText("");
                telefon.setText("");
                POL.setText("");
            }
        });
        
        show.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                frame2.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        edit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                text.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
        delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                text.setText("");
            }
        });
        serchSex.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                First y = new First();
                String rezult = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "<html><h2>Введіть пол");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, y.serchSex(rezult));
            }
        });
        serchCity.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                First y = new First();
                String rezult = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "<html><h2>Введіть місто");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, y.serchCity(rezult));
            }
        });
        serchCode.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                First y = new First();
                String rezult = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "<html><h2>Введіть телефон");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, y.serchAbonent(rezult));
            }
        });
        panel.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Помогите исправить проблему, может там нужно что-то добавить или отнять, изменить. Если нужна будет ещё дополнительная информация, скажите. Буду очень благодарна за помощь)

Comment: У вас в массивах ничего нет, когда вы нажимаете на кнопки поиска, то все стирается.

Comment: Самая первая ошибка, что бросается в глаза, это то что статические члены класса First инициализируются внутри конструктора. Это неправильно. Как вариант, вместо массива String лучше использовать ArrayList<String>, создавать статитески. Потому что массив имеет фиксированный размер, а ArrayList может менять размер. Вторая ошибка это то что у класса First есть конструктор где ничего не происходит, ни один массив не заполняется, и этот конструктор и вызывается везде, естественно все данные пустые. Есть ещё ошибки, но я описал самые главные.